# Devise sessions_controller#create method too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, authentication, devise, newrelic

I am conducting stress tests in our website, the ones that would crash the machine to figure out user limit supported by the system.

The problem is that while monitoring unicorn processes, nothing was really happening, cpu consumption was around 15% to 30% per process.

But when i checked newrelic graphes, i could see that there was a bottle neck in sessions_controller#create method, taking 85% of the time...

Is there a known issue with this method ? Is there a way to speed up thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check the value of `config.stretches` in `config/devise.rb`

Reduce the value and see how it effects performance.

May also be found in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

`config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10`